# Bladecenter-E Power Module fault

Tags: ibm, blade-server, bladecenter, blade-chassis

We have problem on IBM Bladecenter-E

```
  Critical Events
      Power module 2 is off. DC fault.
      Power module 4 is off. DC fault.
  Warnings and System Events
      Insufficient chassis power to support redundancy
```

What is the best solution for this problem?

Comment: Contact your reseller/channel partner. You've got support, right? Right.

Answer (score 2):

How about turning the power back on? And checking why it's off in the first time?

Comment: ...And/Or replacing the failed modules (PM2, PM4).  Like Tom said, in his comment - call IBM.